# jquery to display a div, where am I going wrong

Tags: jquery

I have the code below

```
    <div id="display_form">
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#display_form_button').on('click', function () {
                 $('#main_content').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:Button id="display_form_button" runat="server" Text="Create Form" CssClass="create_form_button"/>
</div>
```

and then i have a div with a large about of content in it such as tables etc

```
    <div id="main_content">
        tables etc
     </div>
```

In the css I have `display:none;` set for the id of main_content so when the page loads it doesn't appear.  I then want it to appear when I click the button.  I have been googling and searching stack overflow for sometime now and cant seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

You show the `#main_content`, not `#input_form`

Should be:

```
$('#input_form').show();
```

Also, your click event is on an element with id `#create_form_button`... so the button needs to have that ID, not class. So change that to:

```
$('#display_form_button').on('click'...
```

Comment: that was a type in my code above I have corrected it, the code above is now correct and my question still stands

Comment: @user2050577 ok, but see my answer for a second issue.

Comment: I dont think it is even executing the jquery for some reason.  As you have proved the code is right.

Answer (score 0):

The button's id is `display_form_button` yet in the jquery code you are doing `$('#create_form_button')`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your Code, If you click the `Button` it shows the `DIV` but it reload the page, So the `DIV` become `Invisible`..

Add `Return false;` in your JQuery and try the same.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_display_form_button').on('click', function () {
            $('#main_content').show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: @user2050577 : What happens it doesn't Show the DIV...?

Comment: nope, this is very strange as sachleen proved the code works but I think I am having trouble as I am using a master page so not sure where to place '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>' and the page I have my button and div on is the deafult.aspx page.

Comment: @user2050577 : Ok If you are using Master Page means then you put your button and div under <asp:Content> right...? So Tell me the ContentPlaceHolderID of <asp:Content>... I will give you a solution

Comment: currently it is set to to '<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">'

Comment: no still doesnt work, im tempted just to bin this jquery and do the show hide on the button click event in vb